Shiny error when doing a simple calcuation with two inputs in reactive({})
New to shiny. I don't understand what I'm doing incorrect here, there's a error about non-numeric argument to binary operator. I can get this to work but when I'm creating a calculation it gives me an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" as i'm clicking the radio buttons. If i remove one of the sets of radio buttons it works, but when i add extra and perform the calculation, so i'm assuming i'm doing something wrong with "reactive" part. I've tried reconfiguring it, with many different permutations. Any help is much appreciated.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel( "Demonstrate Basics" ),
  br(),
  radioButtons( "responsevar1" , label = "label for reactive buttons", c("Low"=1 ,"Medium"=2, "High"=3) , inline=T, selected=character(0) ),
  radioButtons( "responsevar2" , label = "label for reactive buttons", c("Low"=1 ,"Medium"=2, "High"=3) , inline=T, selected=character(0) ),
  
  textOutput("out_reactiveX") ,
  
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("actionvar", label = "Click here for action to happen"),
    actionButton("resetvar", label = "Click to reset buttons")
  ),
  br(),
  textOutput("out_pushCount") ,
  textOutput("out_pushList") ,

)

server <- function(input, output , session) {
  
  
  reactiveX1 <- reactive({  input$responsevar1     })
  reactiveX2 <- reactive({  input$responsevar2     })
  reactiveX <- reactive({  reactiveX1()*reactiveX2()     })

  output$out_reactiveX <- renderText({     reactiveX()   })

  pushCount <- reactiveVal(0)
  pushList <- reactiveVal( NULL )
  
  observeEvent(input$actionvar, {
    pushCount( pushCount() + 1 )
    pushList( c( pushList(), reactiveX() ))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$resetvar, {
    pushCount(0)  # Set the count to 0
    pushList( NULL)
    
  })
  
  output$out_pushCount <- renderText({ pushCount() })
  output$out_pushList <- renderText({ print(  pushList()  ) }) # locks to first item
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Your inputs are "characters". You have to convert to numerics using e.g. as.numeric(input$responsevar1).
